# Finding the indices of the maximum values along the third dimension of an image in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

Assume that I have a 10-dimensional image in Earth Engine. What I want to know is that in which band, the maximum value of each pixel occurs. I'm actually looking for something like the "Numpy.argmax()" function in Python. How can I do this in Earth Engine using the JavaScript api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe do like this:

```
var image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20200101T100319_20200101T100321_T32TQM')
var max = image.reduce(ee.Reducer.max()) // Single band image with max value
var bandIndexes = ee.List.sequence(0, image.bandNames().size().subtract(1))
var maxIndex = ee.ImageCollection(bandIndexes
    .map(function (i) {
      i = ee.Number(i) // When mapping over a list we must cast
      return ee.Image(i) // An image with the index number
        .updateMask(image.select(i).eq(max)) // Mask out if corresponding band isn't max
        .uint8()
    })
  )
  .mosaic() // Reduce collection of indexes to a single unmasked index
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/58766f16930392ba9c668e63921f0930